# Simple if character does not equal

Tags: c, character-encoding

```
void encode(char* dst, const char* src) {
    while (1) {
       char ch = *src;
       if (!ch || ch != '0','1','2','3') { //pseudo-code
          *dst = 0;
          return;
       }

size_t count = 1;
       while (*(++src) == ch)
          ++count;

       *(dst++) = ch;
       dst += sprintf(dst, "%zu", count);
}
```

How can I say, `ch` does not equal a number.. then return. I am trying to get rid of the infinite loop as well.

Comment: Do you know about the `isdigit()` function?

Comment: Also, what's wrong with using *`sscanf("%[0-9]")`*

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
#include <ctype.h>

void encode(char* dst, const char* src) {
    while (1) {
       char ch = *src;
       if (!isdigit(ch)) { //Should works
          *dst = 0;
          return;
   }
   // Rest of the method
}
```

`isdigit(int)` return `true` if the character is an integer (as '1', '2',..., '9') or `false` in the other case.

(I suppose that the infinity loop is done on purpose)

Comment: Perfect - thank you!

Comment: '42' is not valid

Comment: Yeah, you're right, sorry :)

Comment: The `!ch` is redundant, `isdigit` knows about that

Comment: @sgerbhctim can you valid the answer ?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a little code i've made for you, it will parse all the `src` string, and tells if the string is a number or not. The probleme you may have with your `while(1)` is infinite loop and you're only looking for the first caractere so if I pass `2toto` as argument it would say ok it's a number.

This function return true if src if a number and false if not.

```
#include <stdbool.h>

bool encode(char* dst, const char* src) {
  int i = 0;
  char ch;

  while (src[i] != '\0')
    {
      ch = src[i];
      if (!isdigit(ch)) { //pseudo-code                                                                                                                                                                                
        *dst = 0;
        return false;
      }
      i++;
    }
  return true;
}
```

Comment: Oh le beau code :o

Comment: @YaatSuka bah tu sais la piscine ca forge un homme hein.. xD

Comment: what exactly is `'\0'`

Comment: This the null terminated caracter @sgerbhctim it marks the end on a string.

Comment: also, how would i integrate this with my above edit

Comment: `while (*src || (*(++src) == ch))` means while `src[..]` is not finished (`\0`) and while `src[..]` is the same as `ch`

Answer (score 0):

isdigit works, but for completion's sake, this is how you would begin to write your own check for char ranges:

```
void encode(char* dst, const char* src) {
    while (1) {
        char ch = *src;
        // the char numeric value minus the 
        // numeric value of the character '0'
        // should be greater than or equal to
        // zero if the char is a digit,
        // and it should also be less than or
        // equal to 9
        if (!ch || (ch - '0' >= 0 && ch - '0' <= 9)) { 
            *dst = 0;
            return;
        }
        // ...
    }
}
```

As Nicolas says, you need to guarantee that you'll exit the loop though.